# How to properly Update in the papers and authors table

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem that whenever I update a paper it will always error out Unknown variable [Fname]
This is the update function in my controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $PaperID)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'PaperTitle' => 'required',
            'PaperType' => 'required',
            'file' => [
                'required',
                File::types('pdf')
                    ->max(12 * 1024),
            ],
        ]);

        $paper=Papers::find($PaperID);
        

        $file=$request->file;

        $filename=time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $request->file->move('assets', $filename);
                $paper->file=$filename;

            $paper->PaperTitle=$request->PaperTitle;
            $paper->PaperType=$request->PaperType;
            $paper->College=$request->College;
            $paper->DateCompleted=$request->DateCompleted;
            $paper->ContentAdviser=$request->ContentAdviser;
            
            $paper->update();

            $input = $request->all();

            if(count($input['Fname']) > 0){
                for($i = 0 ; $i < count($input['Fname']) ; $i++){
                    
    
                    $author->Fname = $input['Fname'][$i];
                    $author->Lname = $input['Lname'][$i];
                    $author->update();
                }
            }

            return redirect()->back()->with('success','File has been updated.');

    }
```

the storing works fine but update doesn't how to fix this? I want that both papers and authors table will update the papers updates fine but the author does not

Comment: `$paper->update();` should be `$paper->save();`. `update()` expects an array of attributes to update, like `$paper->update(['PaperTitle' => $request->PaperTItle])`, `save()` persists the `$paper` object, with it's modified properties from `$paper->whatever = 'whatever';` (Voting to close as "Not Reproducible"/"Syntax Error"; you're simply calling the wrong method)

Comment: Also, where are you defining `$author`? Right now you have `$author->Fname = ...`, but I don't see anywhere you're calling `$author = ...`

Comment: @TimLewis technically you could call `update` like that since `update` is `fill(...)->save()` so it would be like calling `save()` so it is valid

Comment: have you verified that the request actually has an input named `Fname`? `dd($request->all())` and see if there is a key for `Fname` there ... also where is this `$author` variable defined?

Comment: @TimLewis $author was define as $author = new Authors(); just like that because Fname and Lname are arrays I am having troubles in calling them in their respective papers

Comment: @lagbox Is that so? All these years and I've been assuming incorrectly, or I'm possibly thinking the `Builder` update method, i.e. `Model::where()->update()` vs `Model::first()->update()`. But thanks for the clarification regardless!

Answer (score -1):

## Solution

Use `$paper->save()` — update expects different params.

Try this for updating:

```php
$paper->update($request->validated()->except('file'))
// or
`$paper->update($request->validated()->only(['field1', 'field2', 'etc'))`
```

(of course, you'll want to add validation for all Model attributes)

## Extra credit (PR Review Learning Comments)

### 1. Code Readability

First, add spaces around your `=` & after your `if`'s. Better yet, use a library (like `php-cs-fixer`) to automatically format your code.

### 2. Use a custom UpdatePaperRequest

Using a custom Request rather than using `$request->validate()` helps organize your code. Laravel delegates validation to requests. You can then test the Request separately, create reusable/shared functionality (Traits/Concernst), etc... it's just better trust me :)